# encountered "Uncaught TypeError: auth2.signIn is not a function"

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-plus

I'm a new learner and encountered this error when i tried to follow the Google+ API quick start sample app. Here is the link to this sample:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/samples/php

I have my IIS running correctly with correct PHP support. I also have phpmyadim running on my IIS correctly.

I followed the instruction all the way to Step 3.Run the quick-start app, I got the first issue.

The instruction says input "php -s localhost:4567" in CMD. I followed but received the error "Could not open input file: localhost:4567".

Then I kept going to the next step and visit "http://localhost/signin.php". The webpage correctly showed the Google+ signin button but when I click the button, nothing happened. I pressed F12 then found there is an error:

Uncaught TypeError: auth2.signIn is not a function

```
at Object.signIn [as success] (signin.php:263)
at k (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at y (jquery.min.js:2)
at XMLHttpRequest.d (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I have no idea about this and could anyone help me out?

Comment: Please add the code you are using for signin.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter an error its best to deal with that error and not just move to the next step.

Solution for: `"Could not open input file: localhost:4567"`.

The correct flag is a capital S

> php -S localhost:4567

Documentation [Command line options](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php)

> -S <addr>:<port> Run with built-in web server.